# So I am having this bug where my model in a game is transparent when you look at it from a certain angle

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

[image]

so my question is how would i go about getting rid of that transparency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like flipped normals. Try to select faces of that geometry and in the left toolbar select Shading / UV tab -> Normals: Recalculate. Or select only those "transparent" faces and hit Flip Direction.

Comment: so i don't think i have any normals... i think haha.